# Add columns and preserving rows names

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors like:

```
Monday      1     Monday    2
Tuesday     1     Tuesday   2
Wednesday   1     Wednesday 2
Thursday    1     Thursday  2
Friday      1     Friday    2
```

I want a result like

```
Monday      3     
Tuesday     3     
Wednesday   3     
Thursday    3     
Friday      3
```

but instead i get a result like

```
1         3
2         3
3         3
4         3
5         3
```

I use a Cbind function. How can I keep the rows names, Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Can you provide your data using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: normally one would use `merge` but it is easier to help if you tell us what you did in order to achieve the result that you got

Answer (score 2):

```
a <- c(Monday = 1, Tuesday = 1, Wednesday = 1, Thursday = 1, Friday = 1)
b <- c(Monday = 2, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 2, Thursday = 2, Friday = 2)
a + b

#   Monday   Tuesday Wednesday  Thursday    Friday 
#        3         3         3         3         3 

#To get a dataframe back
stack(a + b)

#  values       ind
#1      3    Monday
#2      3   Tuesday
#3      3 Wednesday
#4      3  Thursday
#5      3    Friday
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rowSums`

```
stack(rowSums(cbind(a, b)))
#  values       ind
#1      3    Monday
#2      3   Tuesday
#3      3 Wednesday
#4      3  Thursday
#5      3    Friday
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative if we want to get a tibble format, we could use:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(ind=names(a), value=a+b)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ind       value
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 Monday        3
2 Tuesday       3
3 Wednesday     3
4 Thursday      3
5 Friday        3
```